# How to modify Rod-Cutting problem to take sizes which increase by more than one

Tags: java, algorithm, dynamic-programming

Here is the code for the classic rod cutting problem. As the code stands, the sizes are 1, 2, 3, and 4, the size of the price array arr[]. How would I modify the code so that the sizes are set to different values other than those given. For example, 1, 2, 3 and 5 instead.

```
 static double cutRod(double price[],int n) 
 { 
     double val[] = new double[n+1]; 
     val[0] = 0; 

     for (int i = 1; i<=n; i++) 
     { 
         double max_val = Integer.MIN_VALUE; 
         for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) 
             max_val = Math.max(max_val,  
                                price[j] + val[i-j-1]); 
         val[i] = max_val; 
     } 

     return val[n]; 
 } 

  public static void main(String args[]) 
 { 
     double arr[] = new double[] {1.2, 3, 5.8, 10.1}; 
     int size = arr.length; 
     System.out.println("Maximum Obtainable Value is " + 
                         cutRod(arr, size)); 
 } 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the classical problem, `j+1` in your inner loop represents the cut sizes possible. If you have custom cut sizes, store those in an array and use them instead of `j + 1`.

In the above program, let `custom_sizes` be the array storing the cuts, eg. 1,2,3,5, etc.

Modifying the above program:

```
 static double cutRod(double price[],int custom_sizes[], int n) 
 { 
   double val[] = new double[n+1]; 
   val[0] = 0; 

   for (int i = 1; i<=n; i++) 
   { 
       double max_val = Integer.MIN_VALUE; 
       for (int j = 0; j < custom_sizes.length; j++) {
           if (i - custom_sizes[j] >= 0)
             max_val = Math.max(max_val,  
                                price[j] + val[i-custom_sizes[j]]); 
       }
       val[i] = max_val; 
   } 
   return val[n];
}
```

Please note that it is assumed that input is valid and that `price` and `custom_sizes` are of equal length = `n`.